# Can I use a 940nm laser diode for a remote control?

Tags: diodes, infrared, laser

Most TV remotes use 940-950nm LEDs. The [TV-B-Gone](http://learn.adafruit.com/tv-b-gone-kit/design-notes#ir-leds) uses a combination of short ranged, wide output and long ranged, narrow output LEDs, to have a combination of easy mark hitting and longer range.

**Say I'm willing to pay the cost for a 940nm laser diode. Could that be used to design a extremely long ranged "sniper" version of the TV-B-Gone?** Or would I just be setting peoples curtains on fire?

I tried searching the web for applications and found uses in hair removal, fat reduction, and defense. The only application remotely (no pun intended) related to my use was as fiber lasers, which I imagine to be a signaling use.

Comment: Wouldn't worry about the curtains (you'd need a lot of power for that) although one issue is eye safety - people don't have a blink response to infrared so it's more dangerous than a visible laser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infrared lasers do work as IR remotes in place of an IR LED. One must keep in mind that the laser needs to be modulated at the requisite carrier frequency (typically 36, 38, 40, 42, 48 or 56 KHz depending on the receiver). This precludes out of the box laser modules which have their on-board current regulation, and do not lend themselves well to modulation at high frequencies. Also, the cheaper TTL-modulated laser modules work up to perhaps 10 or 15 KHz, insufficient for the purpose.

A laser driver with TTL modulation input, that supports the desired modulation frequency and higher, will do the job. For example, [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5VDC-980nm-30mw-Infrared-IR-Laser-Dot-Module-w-TTL-100KHz-/250948341326?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a6dafce4e) works well as an ultra long-range TV remote for my Samsung TV:

[image] (*source: [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5VDC-980nm-30mw-Infrared-IR-Laser-Dot-Module-w-TTL-100KHz-/250948341326?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a6dafce4e)*)

However, here are the two issues with using a laser such as this one:

1. A duty cycle of anywhere over around 5% doesn't work - presumably the IR sensor gets overwhelmed.
2. An IR LED actually works better than a laser as a remote control, because the wider spread of the IR beam ensures that reflected IR from walls and furniture reaches the sensor even if the direct beam is not spot-on to the sensor. With a laser, especially an invisible one, targeting the sensor is quite a challenge, and the collimated beam ensures that reflected signal is nearly non-existent.

In order to aim at the IR sensor on an appliance, one would need to use an infrared visualizing ceramic strip stuck next to the sensor on the appliance, such as [these ones](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Display-Imaging-Board-Graphics-850nm-980nm-IR-Infrared-laser-Visulizer-Detector-/290730799642?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43b0e7f21a):

[image] (*source: [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Display-Imaging-Board-Graphics-850nm-980nm-IR-Infrared-laser-Visulizer-Detector-/290730799642?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43b0e7f21a)*)

(*The keychain bit is just for convenience, since the imaging strips are rather thin and small, hence easy to damage or lose*)

The ceramic material glows greenish when an infrared beam is incident upon it, providing a means for figuring out where the IR laser is aimed at.

---

Summary:

**It *can* be done with a laser, but it is far too much trouble to be worthwhile.**

Comment: IR can be viewed with a digital camera, a cell phone camera will work, put a peace of floppy disk, as a visual filter over the lens. To test it, view a TV remote head on.

Comment: @Optionparty Sorry, doesn't work if the appliance is typical black plastic. A cellphone camera, and even a DSLR, shows nothing at all at even a few meters away.

Comment: Diode lasers aren't naturally collimated. Their output tends to diverge at 35-45 degrees (and not eqaully in every direction). There's optics in those off-the-shelf modules to provide collimation. Which could, in principle, be changed to give a broader beam, or a more divergent beam than usual. But also, these optics probably add as much to the expense of using a laser as the laser itself does.

Comment: @ThePhoton Fair point - my experience is limited to modules with the optics integrated. Presumably without the optics, the range would also be correspondingly reduced?

Comment: The laser generates X amount of power, which is spread over an expanding spot size as the beam diverges. Compared to an LED, you'd still have more power with less divergence. But compared to a collimated beam, much less power per square inch at the center of the spot if you'r emore than a few mm away.